# Mouseenter / Mouseleave creates flickering effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, show, mouseover

I have a black icon which I would like to turn blue while the cursor is hovering over it. It does turn blue if I keep the cursor still, but if I move it around, the icon starts flickering blue and black. I made a jfiddle to illustrate:

http://jsfiddle.net/8t2whdop/3/

And here's the code in my view:

```
<%= image_tag("IconBlack.png", class: "link", id: "icon-black") %>
<%= image_tag("IconBlue.png", class: "link", id: "icon-blue") %>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#icon-blue').hide();
  $('#icon-black').mouseenter(function () {
    $('#icon-black').hide();
    $('#icon-blue').show();
  });
  $('#icon-black').mouseleave(function () {
    $('#icon-black').show();
    $('#icon-blue').hide();
  });
</script>
```

Apparently this is a common problem with mouseenter/leave considering the number of similar questions. This isn't a duplicate however, because I tried all the solutions that I found, and none of them fixed my particular problem. For example, I tried all different combinations of mouseover/out/enter/leave/toggle/hover. How can I stop the flickering effect?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to do this with JavaScript as the same hover effect can be easily done using CSS?

Comment: @Jay Can I switch images with CSS though?

Comment: @user3739453 You can easily switch background image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

by simply using the right selector `$('#icon-blue').mouseleave` ***[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/8t2whdop/5/)***

```
$('#icon-blue').hide();
$('#icon-black').mouseenter(function () {
  $('#icon-black').hide();
  $('#icon-blue').show();
});
$('#icon-blue').mouseleave(function () { // the #icon blue!!!
  $('#icon-black').show();
  $('#icon-blue').hide();
});
```

Also note that what you need can be done in **[pure CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/8t2whdop/8/)**

In either cases it's easier to write JS and CSS for such things if you wrap your *icons* inside a common **parent element** -- cause than, all you need is to target `:hover` or in jQ `.hover()` that parent.

Comment: Wow. Should've known it was that simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

First, you could do this with CSS only, no JS needed :

http://jsfiddle.net/8t2whdop/7/

HTML

```
<div id="icon">
</div>
```

CSS

```
#icon{
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    background: black;
}
#icon:hover{
    background: blue;
}
```

Then I'll explain why your code is giving this result (expected):

When you hover the black icon, you call jQuery `hide` method on it which is setting `display: none;` on the black icon (after a few milliseconds) thus triggering the `mouseleave` event. So it instantly shows the black icon again which triggers the `mouseenter` event and so on...

If you wan't (or need) to do it with JS, you could use a wrapper div to catch events (but even so, using two different divs for each background is not efficient):

HTML

```
<div id="icon">
    <div id="icon-black"></div>
    <div id="icon-blue"></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('#icon-blue').hide();
$('#icon').mouseenter(function () {
  $('#icon-black').hide();
  $('#icon-blue').show();
});
$('#icon').mouseleave(function () {
  $('#icon-black').show();
  $('#icon-blue').hide();
});
```

See fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/8t2whdop/6/

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be better solved using css, if you just want the color to be changed on hover

```
#icon{
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    background-color: black;
}

#icon:hover{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

If you need to change the image of the box:

```
#icon{
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    background-image: url("IconBlack.png");
}

#icon:hover{
    background-image: url("IconBlue.png");

}
```

Comment: Are there any advantages to this method? For example, is it faster or less prone to bugs?